# can ExecuteReader work in if condition in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to delete the data from database, but before execution of `ExecuteReader` in C# asp.net I want to check if data exist or not.

I want to work like this, if any possible solution please help.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDelete", scon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox6.Text.ToString());
scon.Open();
//want to check here before execution. is this possible?

if(cmd.ExecuteReader() == TextBox1.Text)
{
    // then execution
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
else 
{
    Lblmsg.Text =- "Record doesn't exist";
}
```

Comment: You could be more clear if you add the code of the stored procedure.

Comment: `Create proc spDelete
@id int
as
Begin
Delete from employees where id = @id
end`

Comment: @Steve stored procedure

Comment: Instead of calling ExecuteReader, call ExecuteNonQuery and get the return value. If it is zero then there is no record to delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to execute your stored procedure. In your case the correct one is [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns the number of records affected by the command. If your stored procedure deletes the record the return value will be not zero, otherwise (no record matching the ID parameter) the return will be zero

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDelete", scon))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox6.Text);
    scon.Open();
    int numRecordsDeleted = scon.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if(numRecordsDeleted == 0)
        Lblmsg.Text = "Record doesn't exist";
    else
        Lblmsg.Text = "Record deleted";
}
```

Finally, are you sure that your ID field is a string? Passing a parameter with AddWithValue is dangerous, you should always specify the correct datatype.
For example, if ID is a field with Integer datatype then you should write

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to check whether the reader contains records or not. if so you can full fill this by using the code like the following:

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(rdr.HasRows)
    {
      //execute the statements;             
    }
    else 
    {
       Lblmsg.Text =- "Record doesn't exist";
    }
```

Comment: this is not working. after the execution of reader, it never checks if codition

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are running a delete command in a stored procedure.  In this case you do not want to use ExecuteReader, but [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx).  This will return the number of rows effected, which if it is equal to 1 then you know you deleted 1 row.

Depending on your stored procedure you want to use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx).  Read up on it and see what you think.

I assume you sanitize user input and have code to validate the text box value is a number?

Comment: textbox mode set to number